# special character "/" from angular4 to WebAPI2

Tags: angular, parameters, webapi2

i need to invoke web api2 from angular4
my url looks like below
my url looks like api/schedule/getdata/date/2018-04-18/utilityid/utilityname/poolid/pool/name
where poolid contains special characters for example: "pool/name". how can i pass this special character (/) from angular4 to WebAPI2.

I tried with FromUri at WebAPI level- but still failure

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: You'll most likely have to escape those characters. `/` for example is escaped with `%2F`

Comment: Look into this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: I tried with the below url as you said- escaped with %2F- 
http://localhost:65172/api/schedule/schedulinglevelpool/day/2018-04-18/utility/EQB/pool/EQB%2FEQT%20LOCAL- still failed

Comment: Did you un-escape the character in the endpoint code?

Comment: What does the API endpoint routing code look like?

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "MyApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Failed to load http://localhost:65172/api/schedule/schedulinglevelpool/day/2018-04-19/utility/EQB/pool/EQB/EQT%20LOCAL: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.- this is the error message

Comment: Sounds like the format of the request parameters is correct, but you don't have CORS enabled.

Comment: public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            //cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Filters.Add(new ModelStateValidatorFilter());

            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();

            SetJsonCamelCaseSerializer(config);- CORS enabled